# Changing the font size

Tags: wordpress, fonts

I'm trying to change the font size of the subcategories on my website. It's wordpress based site with a premium press theme. I was told that this may be done on cPanel under php. However I'm not very good with scripts so I don't want to change anything that might harm my site the URL is http://worldtownimports.com . I've already tried changing the size in css but it has no affect. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What are "subcategories" on your Page? Headlines? Nav Items? Copy Text? Provide example code!

Answer (score 1):

You where right in wanting to use CSS. Inside Wordpress you can edit the themes files, including css.

I'd suggest when editing files inside Wordpress to copy it out of the editor and paste into a editor on your computer make change then paste them all back in.

To make this change, you need to adjust the `font-size` attribute for those elements. In this case you want to change the `#objectClassifieds a`; This appears on line 318.

The complete line is.

```
#objectClassifieds a { text-decoration:none; }
```

You can add the `font-size: ;` attribute to it giving your font in px, percents, ems or any other standard.

(Assumed Sub-Categories where the block of tags under Website Categories, like Aircraft, Aircraft Parts, etc)